# Set the Creation Date of a file to that of another file with Powershell

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, powershell

Can someone help me get this line right?

```
powershell Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath '[NewVideo]' -Name CreationTimeUtc -Value ('[CreationTimeOfOldVideo]' -as [Datetime])
```

I am trying to rotate video files 90 degrees, while preserving the creation date of the original file. I have found the way to do the rotation using ffmpeg, but am stuck trying to copy the creation date to the new file. A search made me conclude that it should be possible with powershell (of which I know hardly anything)

This is what I have so far:

```
FOR /r %%I in (*.avi, *.mp4) DO CALL :loopbody "%%~fI" "%%~dpnI_%%~xI" "%%~tI"
GOTO :EOF
:loopbody
ffmpeg -i %1 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 4000k -c:a libvo_aacenc -q:a 100 -map_metadata 0 -preset veryslow -tune film -movflags +faststart %2
powershell Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath '%2' -Name CreationTimeUtc -Value ('%3' -as [Datetime])
```

Which was thankfully copied from another user at this forum.
The problem lies in the last line. The %3 variable is the cmd date ($~tI) of the old file, which usually is the LastModifiedDate, not the CreationDate. I need powershell to set the creationdate of the new file the same as the creationdate of the old file. I have done some experimenting with [oldfile].CreationTimeUTC, to no avail.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thx @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, works like a dream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example Powershell command to get creation date of file:

```
(Get-ChildItem c:\path\yourFile.txt).CreationTime
```

Example Powershell command to set creation date of file:

```
(Get-ChildItem c:\path\yourFile.txt).CreationTime = '01/01/1900 12:42AM'
```

So as a one-liner to be used in the existing script as-is (instead of that last line) try something like:

`powershell (Get-ChildItem '%2').CreationTime = (Get-ChildItem '%1').CreationTime`

This will set the creation time of the new file (%2) to the creation time of the old file (%1).

This assumes `%2` contains the new file's path/name and `%1` contains the old file's path/name. :)

Comment: You can also use `LastWriteTime` instead of `CreationTime` to get/set file modification date.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a Powershell script that overwrites the creation dates of all videos to new videos from the original videos, between two folders! The file names must match the original files.

```
$originalVideosDirectory = "original directory path"
$encodedVideosDirectory = "encoded directory path"


# Get filenames and modification dates of original videos
$originalVideos = Get-ChildItem -Path $originalVideosDirectory -File | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        ModificationDate = $_.LastWriteTime
    }
}

# Get the filenames of newly created videos
$encodedVideos = Get-ChildItem -Path $encodedVideosDirectory -File

# Identify the newly created videos that match the original videos
foreach ($encodedVideo in $encodedVideos) {
    $originalVideo = $originalVideos | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $encodedVideo.Name }
    if ($originalVideo) {
        $modificationDate = $originalVideo.ModificationDate

        # Set the creation date of the new video
        $encodedVideo.CreationTime = $modificationDate
        $encodedVideo.LastWriteTime = $modificationDate

        # Check date setting
        $encodedVideo.Refresh()
        Write-Host "$($encodedVideo.Name) creation date changed to: $($encodedVideo.CreationTime)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].